# Deploy only changed files with Github actions

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to deploy only the changed files in a Github repo with Github actions? I use the following workflow yml file:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: deploy
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: deploy file
        uses: wlixcc/SFTP-Deploy-Action@v1.0
        with:
          username: 'XXX'
          server: 'deploy.eu2.XXX.com'
          ssh_private_key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }} 
          local_path: './*'
          remote_path: './'
          args: '-o ConnectTimeout=5'
```